# add links for blade php pages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have developed several pages for my applications. Now I need to add link for these pages. Till now I was opening these pages via url browsing.

My web.php page

```
// for books
Route::get('/book','BookController@create');
Route::post('/book','BookController@store');
Route::get('/book/{id}','BookController@edit');
Route::patch('/book/{id}', 'BookController@update');

// for ordered books
Route::get('/order','OrderedBookController@create');
Route::post('/order','OrderedBookController@store');
Route::get('/billSearch','OrderedBookController@searchBill');
Route::post('/billSearch','OrderedBookController@billPay');
Route::post('/billSearch/{id}', 'OrderedBookController@pay');

// for Books Out
Route::get('/booksout','BooksOutController@create');
Route::post('/booksout','BooksOutController@store');
```

List of pages corresponding to the routes

```
book.blade.php
edit.blade.php
booksin.blade.php
booksout.blade.php
```

local host url to browse these pages are ::

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/book
http://127.0.0.1:8000/order
http://127.0.0.1:8000/billSearch // for Route::get('/billSearch','OrderedBookController@searchBill');
http://127.0.0.1:8000/booksout
```

How can I create link in my web apps since I am browsing my pages via routes, not by pages ?

Comment: Like any other link: `<a href="/book">Book</a>`.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/urls

Comment: the best way is to create named route and use this names in href
href="{{route('route_name')}}"

Answer (score 5):

Use `route()` or `url()` functions.

e.g. in blade view:

```
<a href="{{ route('book') }}"></a>
```

More in [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/urls)

Answer (score 2):

You may links different pages in laravel by using one of the two ways

1: By including url which you define in your route in the blade href

```
 Route::post('/billSearch', 'OrderedBookController@pay');
```

therefore in your blade link

```
<a href="/billSeach"> </a>
```

2:By using the name of the route

```
 Route::post('/billSearch', 'OrderedBookController@pay')->name('bill);
```

Therefore in your blade view

```
<a href="{{route('bill'}}"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

just insert your routes like this:

```
<a href="/book">Book</a> --> http://127.0.0.1:8000/book
<a href="/billSearch ">Bill Search</a> --> http://127.0.0.1:8000/billSearch
```